# Is there a way to display the URL without the file extension in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/u/', $link);
echo $_COOKIE[] = end($link_array);
```

Does anyone know how I could shave off 4 characters at the end or a totally different method thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the basename function

```
$basename = basename($link, '.php');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot just found that out right before you said